# Bring value from an editext to another activty

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I have class A in which I have 4 edit texts that I use to search in my database. With these 4 edit texts I build an URL that I then send to a ServiceHandler that will give me the results in JSON format. The problem is that I want to take these 4 edittexts and give them to my URL builder that is in a DIFFERENT activity. Each time I try I get NullPointerException.
How can I give my service Handler these 4 edit texts?

Comment: please show me your code so i am able to help soon.

Comment: Impossible for anyone to answer this without seeing your code

Comment: well, someone did answer it without the code so I guess your impossible is his possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data from one activity to another activity. You can use the intent like below -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("message1", edittext1.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("message2", edittext2.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("message3", edittext3.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("message4", edittext4.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity2 in onCreate(), you can get the String messages by retrieving a Bundle

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message1 = bundle.getString("message1");
String message2 = bundle.getString("message2");
String message3 = bundle.getString("message3");
String message4 = bundle.getString("message4");
```

Comment: yeah, so I am writing again to thank you once more: my app is no longer crashing and it is working properly :) thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). As you mentioned using a Service, however as others have said it is not clear from your question and lack of code what you want to do.

Using a broadcast receiver you can send and receive messages between activities, tasks and services.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not allowed to show the code :\, but thanks this is useful :D